# Nav bar not sticking on scroll

Tags: bootstrap-4, position, css-position, navbar

I have a navbar react component that has the html below, which uses bootstrap. I would like for it to stick to the top once it scrolls there (there is a page of content above it). I tried applying `position-sticky` to the wrapper div and I also applied `sticky-top` to the nav itself but none of these worked. It just scrolls out of view.

```
<div className="d-none d-md-block position-sticky">
      <nav className="navbar sticky-top bg-dark navbar-dark navbar-expand">
        <a className="navbar-brand" href="#initialImage">
          name
        </a>
        <ul className="navbar-nav">
          <li className="nav-item">
            <a className="nav-link text-white font-weight-bold" href="#">
              Home
            </a>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <a className="nav-link text-white font-weight-bold" href="#">
              Shop Collection One
            </a>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <a className="nav-link text-white font-weight-bold" href="#">
              Shop Collection Two
            </a>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <a className="nav-link text-white font-weight-bold" href="#">
              A Message 
            </a>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <a className="nav-link text-white font-weight-bold" href="#">
              Contact
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you consider using Bootstrap?

Comment: @RohanRao I am currently using bootstrap. All the classes I use above are bootstrap classes.

Comment: Can you provide all of the relevant markup? What's above and below that nav?

Comment: Essentially there is one navbar that is fixed to the top that only displays on small screens. Then I have a page of content followed by another navbar (the one I described above) that I want to show only on larger screens and have its position be sticky-top. The markup provided by @RohanRao is exactly what I want but I only want it to show on larger screens that is why I have the extra wrapper container as shown above in my code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have couple of incorrect and unnecessary things out in your markup.

1. You need not to use a separate div for making a BS Navbar responsive. BS provides an in-built class for it.
2. Next, your li items are not proper. When I use your code even with BS stylesheet links it still shows the normal ul links.

I have formatted the links for you (**taken from w3schools**) and modified as per your requirement.

**Please note:** While running the code snippet, you might find some unusual behavior of the links, because of screen size. I would recommend you to run this code in web browser. Bootstrap version used is **4.0**.

**VERSION 1:** This version is simple. Just sticks the navbar upon scrolling.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="height:1500px">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My WebsiteName</a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Shop Collection One</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Shop Collection Two</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">A Message</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top:80px">
    <h3>Top Fixed Navbar</h3>
    <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
    <h1>Scroll this page to see the effect</h1>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**VERSION 2:** This navbar is modification of the Version 1, where initially the navbar is not sticky, but when you scroll and reach a certain scroll amount, it sticks the navbar.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="height:1500px">

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <br>
    <h3>Hello World</h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
  </div>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark sticky-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MyWebSite</a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Shop Collection One</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Shop Collection Two</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">A Message</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div class="container-fluid"><br>
    <p>Some example text. Some example text. Some example text. Some example text. Some example text.</p>
    <p>Some example text. Some example text. Some example text. Some example text. Some example text.</p>
    <p>Some example text. Some example text. Some example text. Some example text. Some example text.</p>
    <p>Some example text. Some example text. Some example text. Some example text. Some example text.</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I actually have two nav bars: one for small screens and one for large screens. In my original post I show the one that follows a page of content that's used for full screens. Thus, I only show this navbar fully expanded and I have another nav bar for mobiles that appears at the very top (no need for scrolling -- it will appear right at the top and stay fixed). I want to hide this navbar completely on small screens that is why I wrap it with d-none. Is there any way to do this? Your solution works only when I do not add the wrapper of <div className="d-none d-md-block position-sticky">